# Is the order in which cookies show up in document.cookie deterministic?

Tags: javascript, cookies

It's possible to have two cookies with the same name but different values in `document.cookie` if a subdomain and a domain set the same cookie.

For example, if I:

1. Visit `subdomain.domain.com` first, which sets a `my_cookie=foo`cookie.
2. And then visit `domain.com` second, which sets a `my_cookie=boo`cookie.

`document.cookie` in Chrome 81 will show `my_cookie=foo; my_cookie=boo` on `subdomain.domain.com`, in the order in which the cookies were set with the most recent cookie last.

My question is, can this ordering be relied on (and is there a rfc that talks about this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly found this in an RFC about not relying on cookie orders between different subdomians:

[image]

reference: https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt

`4.2.2.  Semantics`